# MySqlConnection.Open() with Connector/NET 6.9.6 can't connect to MySQL Server 8.0.29

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector, ubuntu-20.04

I recently update our MySQL server version from `8.0.28` to `8.0.29` on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

After the update my system was unexpectedly returning an error when connecting to database.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object on `MySqlConnection.Open()`.

I'm using `MySQL .Net Connector 6.9.6`

*The system is already established*

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, the only possible reason could be that your `MySqlConnection` reference is `Nothing`. Maybe you could provide ALL the relevant information, like the stack trace of the exception to show where the exception was actually throw, i.e. on that call or somewhere within that call. If it's within then the code and connection string would be relevant too.

Comment: What .NET Framework issue?

Comment: @John, everything is working before the update to version 8.0.29. Currently I'm using .Net Framework 4.5.1 and upgrading to .Net Connector 8.0 requires to change the .Net Framework of the application to a higher version and this might cause more issues

Comment: It only requires .NET Framework 4.5.2, which is just a service release over 4.5.1, so I'm not sure that that's a reason not to upgrade Connector/Net. You probably ought to have made that move long ago.

Comment: The system is running for years and there are dependencies that I need to consider.